# Navigate to the changed lines of code in a file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a huge class in which I changed couple of lines in different places. Is there a way (shortcut) to navigate through changed lines of code in the file and not to scroll all the way up/down?

Comment: Please check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#20c948f4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*From the official IntelliJ IDEA documentation:*

> ## [Navigate between changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate-between-changes)
>
> If you edit a file that is under [version control](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-version-control.html), IntelliJ IDEA
> provides several ways to move back and forth with the updates. In
> particular, you can use the navigation commands, keyboard shortcuts,
> and the change markers.
>
> - Press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> / <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd><kbd>⇧
>   Shift</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>.
> - In the main menu, go to **Navigate | Next / Previous Change**.
> - Click a [change marker](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-changes-information.html#local_changes), and then click the ↑ (the Previous Change button) or ↓ (the Next Change button).
>
> To navigate to the place of your last edit, press <kbd>⌘
> Сmd</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌫ Backspace</kbd> or select **Navigate
> | Last Edit Location** from the main menu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Control + Alt + Left|Right Arrow for current KeyMap

Refer this screen-shot for your reference in case you are having different mapping.
[image]